# RShiny Columns Overlap With Picture

Tags: r, shiny

I'm having problems with my RShiny when I resize the browser. I noticed there are several similar topics but those are when it is words and can be solved with the wrap words input. However mine is a picture and a bunch of words.

[When browser is big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEOLx.png)

[When resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL5Av.png)

```
###codes above

output$img1 <-renderUI({
if(input$Category == "Cleanser"){
  img(width = 175, height = 175, src = "Cleansers.png", style = "margin-left:15px; margin-top:10px")
}

### rest of codes

  output$text1<-renderUI({
summary<-read_excel(paste0("Summary/",input$Category,".xlsx"),sheet = 1)
summary$Price<-as.integer(summary$Price)
dat<-calcul()
product=paste(dat[input$table1_cell_clicked$row,1])
w1=which(summary$`Product Name`==product)

###relevant part###
fluidRow(tags$head(tags$style(
  "body { word-wrap: break-word; }"
)),
  column(2,uiOutput("img1",inline = T))
  ,column(9,h3("Description",style = 'margin-left:10px'),
  p(summary$Description[w1], style = "margin-left:10px"))     
)
})
```

I used fluidRow() to make the columns, I tried using the word-wrap thing but it doesn't work still. Can someone help me out ? Thanks so much!

Comment: Maybe adding a `margin-right:15px` to your `img` works. If not, please provide a small working example such that we can provide better help.

Comment: Hey, I added the margin right but it still doesn't work